# HBase printing hadoop.native.library is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-native-library

I've installed hbase-0.98-6-hadoop2 to use with hadoop-2.4.1, however when I start the hbase shell I get the following message:

> Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.library is deprecated.
>   Instead, use io.native.lib.avaiable

I know that such a message is just a log info, however I would like to know what I can do in order to solve such problem. I've tried a lot of things, among them, basically all of them was about put the $HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native into my classpath, java.library.path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH; none of those could solve the problem.

Is there someone that can help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Dumb question: you did *check* your `hbase-site.xml` for `hadoop.native.library`, right?

Comment: I've never heard about such attribute, what does not means that much since is the first time I'am installing hbase/hadoop. Anyway, I just add it to my hbase-site.xml using this property pointing to my $hadoop_install/lib/native and the same error jump off.